# Polymorphic function calls in Java?

Tags: java, interface, event-handling, polymorphism

Is it possible to polymorphically pass a function to an object array in Java?

I'm trying to create an event-based system, and interfaces simply isn't as versatile as I would like it to be.

As a result, I would like to be able to pass any function to the event manager, and have it execute the function on next iteration.

Comment: TL;DR - no it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to be able to pass any function to the event manager

Wouldn't we all.  Unfortunately, Java doesn't have first-class functions or even function pointers.  So we're stuck with interfaces and anonymous classes, until Java 8 at least.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have your event manager execute `Runnable`s, and wrap your method call with one? (This is the approach Swing took.)

```
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

EventQueue.doLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new Foo().doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: The asynchronous nature of `EventQueue.invokeLater` is a semantic shift in the program, which is pretty heavy machinery to trot out until we know what the application is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Interfaces aren't versatile enough for you - you can do anything you like with interfaces, certainly as much as you could do with passing pure functions.

Typically you would just define a single event handler interface:

```
public interface EventHandler {
  public ReturnType handle(ParamType param);
}
```

Then you could implement that interface with any number of different handler classes. The handler objects can even contain their own state if that is useful.

Anything you define that implements the interface can then be used polymorphically, e.g. stored in an array so that they can be called in response to a specific event..

Comment: Yes, you can do anything you like with interfaces, but you can do it much more succinctly and clearly with functions.  See C#'s lambdas and events, or, even better, play with a functional language.  You're only creating cruft when you define a one-method interface where the method's sole job is to be overridden with lambda wannabees like anonymous classes.

Comment: Sure the Java syntax is more verbose (I code in Clojure most of the time, so I certainly appreciate the elegance of functional languages!). But from a practical perspective, it works just as well and gives you all the flexibility you need, which I think is what the OP was asking.....

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support first-class functions. 
But you can do almost that by using anonymous classes or using EventHandler class.

This is from Java Docs.

The simplest use of EventHandler is to install a listener that calls a method on the target object with no arguments. In the following example we create an ActionListener that invokes the toFront method on an instance of javax.swing.JFrame.

```
myButton.addActionListener(
    (ActionListener)EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, frame, "toFront"));
```

When myButton is pressed, the statement frame.toFront() will be executed. One could get the same effect, with some additional compile-time type safety, by defining a new implementation of the ActionListener interface and adding an instance of it to the button:

```
//Equivalent code using an inner class instead of EventHandler.
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.toFront();
    }
});
```